# How to use OpenCV GeneralizedHoughTransform class with Python?

Tags: python, opencv, hough-transform

I'm trying to code a basic example of use of GeneralizedHoughBallard class using OpenCV 3.4.1 and Python 3.7.1

When I try to create a new instance of GeneralizedHoughBallard class:

```
import cv2
alg = cv2.createGeneralizedHoughBallard()
```

I get the error:

> AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'createGeneralizedHoughBallard'

Also I've tried to show all the Hough-methods:

```
print([x for x in dir(cv2) if 'Hough' in x])
```

And the result: `['HoughCircles', 'HoughLines', 'HoughLinesP', 'HoughLinesPointSet']`

So I haven't the basic functions. How can I import it? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems OpenCV 3.4.1 does not have it. In OpenCV v4.0.X its called `GeneralizedHoughBallard`. You may want to update your OpenCV version.

```
python -m pip install --upgrade opencv-python
```

Checking the Hough-methods:

```
import cv2
print(cv2.__version__)
print([x for x in dir(cv2) if 'Hough' in x])
```

> 4.0.0.21
>
> ['GeneralizedHough', 'GeneralizedHoughBallard', 'GeneralizedHoughGuil', 'HoughCircles', 'HoughLines', 'HoughLinesP', 'HoughLinesPointSet']

Comment: Could you help find a simple example of using GeneralizedHoughGuil with python? Maybe you have one..

Comment: Do you mean `GeneralizedHoughBallard`?

Comment: I just need to make simple arbitrary objects finding, but I read that Guil() is better. I think any example will suit me.

Comment: Take at look at [this](http://www.itriacasa.it/generalized-hough-transform/) and [this](https://alyssaq.github.io/2014/understanding-hough-transform/). I recommend you open a separate question for this since it deviates from your original post.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be totally supported in Python, please check it here
[opencv forum link](http://answers.opencv.org/question/211122/how-to-use-opencv-generalizedhoughtransform-class-with-python/)

But somehow possible to do it by rebuilding opencv and dealing with `CV_EXPORTS_W`